# Are the variables contained in the PayPal IPN querystring always sent from PayPal in the same exact order?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

It does not matter whether the variables always appear, I just need to know if when they do, they are always in the same order. Thanks for helping.

Comment: You need to know why?

Comment: I am using Lambda and api Gateway for the back end. When api gateway gets the query string, it reorders them and places them in a parameter list. So I am unable to send an exact copy of the string to the lambda function that handles it and as a result I am unable to reconstruct it in order to send the 'exact' params in the 'exact' order back to Paypal for validation.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a bad idea to rely on the order. Even if they're currently ordered, that may change in future.

Comment: Yes, but it appears to be my only option.